# Django 2.0 CreateView not working

Tags: django

I am very new in Django. Not sure whether this is a bug or an error.

Here is my model in an app called gcbv (for generic class-based view)

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import TimeStampModel
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class Vehicle(TimeStampModel):
    maker = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model_year = models.IntegerField()
    vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    vehicle_model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     website = models.URLField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        x = self.maker + ' ' + self.vehicle_model
        return x
```

And here are the URLs:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import reverse
#from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

app_name = 'gcbv'

urlpatterns = [
    path('sub1/', views.SubView.as_view(), name='sub1'),
    path('vehicle_list/', views.VehicleListView.as_view(),
        name = 'vehicle_list'),
    path('vehicle/<str:slug>/', 
       views.VehicleDetailView.as_view(), 
        name='vehicle_detail'),
    path('vehicle/create', views.VehicleCreateView.as_view(),
        name='vehicle_create'),    
    path('', views.IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

And here is the relevant view:

```
class VehicleCreateView(CreateView):    
    model = Vehicle
    fields = ['maker', 'model_year', 'vehicle_type', 'slug',
        'vehicle_model', 'website', 'email', 'notes']
    labels = {'maker':'Maker', 'model_year':'Year', 
        'vehicle_type':'Type', 'vehicle_model':'Model',
        'website':'Website', 'email':'Email', 'notes':'Notes'}
```

Here is the template:

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
    <h1>Vehicle Create for GCBV</h1>
    <form action="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h1>End Vehicle Create for GCBV</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

It looks as if the data aren't saved in the database, but when i'm adding the same data by hand directly in the admin page, everything works fine. I've attached another screenshot showing that `VehicleDetailView` has found the relevant template and rendered the information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NB:** Everything worked fine when I use function views and regex instead of path.

---

**Form**
[image: rendered form template]

**After submit**
[image: after clicking submit]

**List**
[image: after clicking submit]

**Details**
[image: after clicking submit]

OK, this is what we septuagenarians call a "senior moment". I have been staring at this code for two days and did not see the obvious.

method="POST"!

NOT

action="POST"

Many, many thanks

Comment: As stated in the answer below, you are calling the attribute `action` when it should be `method='post'`

Answer (score 1):

In the fourth line of your template, method should be equal to "post"

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %} 

{% block body_block %}

 <h1>Vehicle Create for GCBV</h1> 

<form method="POST" action=""> 
{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form> 
<h1>End Vehicle Create for GCBV</h1>
 {% endblock %}
```